# iOS addChildViewController with AdMob [iPhone, Objective C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, admob

i'm trying to reuse [this AdMobViewController class](https://gist.github.com/calitb/94181707419f29e56a9c)

i applied this like described in implementation sample and looks it works ok, but my view moves up and it's header under the actionbar now. 
could you please advice how to move it back? 
btw: i haven't experience with admob - does test device key only allows to test device on phone when app installed throw xcode, and won't be used when user download it from market?so user will see real ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found that method viewDidLayoutSubviews in provided class calculate size but don't takes into account bar heig